# How to set up cURL to retrieve data from other site(s)

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I got stuck while trying to set up cURL to retrieve data from other site(s)

Here is my situation.

I have 2 websites :

- A
- B

Website `A` sent data to website `B` as json format.
Of course, website `A` will have to encode all of it data before sending out - that's done.

Let the :

- username = test
- password = 1234

Website `B` just need run this command

`curl --user test:1234 http://localhost/api/`

They will then get the json file, and make anything out of it.

---

But, what if I have to do a mutiple cURL request.
SO I want to write a php script to do that. 
This is what I have so far :

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api/");
$fp = fopen("api.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

**Questions**

- While doing it this way, I am not sure how to configure the `username` and `password`.
- After, knowing where to set the `username` and `password`, where should I do the decoding of the json ?
- After that, how do I display those data that I just decoded in a HTML/PHP format ?
- How do I test it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Set the username and password

Website B is using [HTTP Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). This is a authentication method via HTTP headers. You'll have to set the username and password in the **Authorization** header. This can be done With the cUrl module for PHP like this:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);`

### Decode your result

Assuming you just need the JSON data that website B is returning. Use the following option. It will make `curl_exec()` return the HTTP body instead of outputting it directly.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

For the list of options that can be used with the PHP curl module check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) on `curl_setopt()`. Now you are ready to make your request with cUrl using `curl_exec()` like this:

`$body = curl_exec($ch);`

Then decode the JSON data, for the sake of simplicity lets decode it to a PHP array:

`$data = json_decode($body, true);`

### Test your code

In my opinion PHP is not a language which offers great testing features. Putting that aside, most of the time I test my code in an interactive shell. To start testing your scenario in an interactive shell you should have PHP CLI installed on your system. In linux this is straight forward. Start an interactive PHP shell with the following command:

`php -a`

Now you can start putting together your scenario.

```
php > $ch = curl_init('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two');
php > curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
php > $body = curl_exec($ch);
php > var_dump($body);
string(39) "{
   "one": "two",
   "key": "value"
}
"
php > $data = json_decode($body, true);
php > print_r($data);
Array
(
    [one] => two
    [key] => value
)
```

Comment: I like your answer too. I got a couple questions. 1- what is the diff between `$body = curl_exec($ch);` and just `curl_exec($ch);` or do we need both.

Comment: No you just need `$body = curl_exec($ch);`. When you are using `curl_exec()` cUrl will make a request to website B and it will store the response in the variable $body. Basicly its like entering the url in your browser and store the page you see in $body.

Comment: I noticed, you didn't use `$fp = fopen("distributor_api.txt", "w");` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);` Are they optional OR maybe extra stuffs that I don't really need ?

Comment: Do you mind update your answer and add one last thing ? What the `whole file` should look like at the end ? I am sure that a lot of people will beneficial by your answer on this. [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/cURL_test.php) is my final file look like. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your question does not clarify what you want to do with the data you receive from website B. If you just need the array you only have to use    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER and CURLOPT_USERPWD.

Comment: Hmm ...  I just want to display it in HTML/PHP format. Simple. I said it on my post `After that, how do I display those data that I just decoded in a HTML/PHP format ?`

Comment: JSON is a data format. Lets say the JSON returned by website B is {"one": "<html><body><h1>Hulk is green</h1></body></html>"}. Now following the example from my post you can echo the HTML with `echo $data['one']`.

Comment: `<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/api/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "test:1234");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
` What do you think about my code ? No mistake right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67501/discussion-between-charlie-vieillard-and-iggy).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure username and password like this

```
//cURL Options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'test:1234',  // username:test pass:1234
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(‘Content-type: application/json’) ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
);

// Setting curl options like this
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result = curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
```

**How do you test it?**
I would put all that in a .php file and call it on the browser to debug to keep it simple.

Comment: I'm a little confuse, when you do `$username . “:” . $password,`, can you edit your answer, for username = `test` and password = `1234`. Ratherthan that I like your answer. +1 @unixmiah

Comment: I noticed, you didn't use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);` so what'll happen to my `$fp = fopen("distributor_api.txt", "w");`. Do I need it ? [Here is the FINAL look of my file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/curl-config.php) ...

Comment: you can use $fp = fopen("distributor_api.txt", "w") file with $result = curl_exec($ch) then write the contents to the file with fwrite($fp, $result)

Comment: Write a content to a file ? May I ask why do we need to do that ? If you don't mind, could you please take a look at [THIS](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/test.php) to see if this is what the final look should be ? I have not include fwrite because I don't know why do we need that yet. Thanks